# Why Does Double Get Extra digits after decimal?

Tags: java, double, precision

I am running this code

```java
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double d = Math.log(125)/Math.log(5);
        float f = (float)(Math.log(125f)/Math.log(5f));
        System.out.printf("DOUBLE: %.20f\n", d);
        System.out.printf("FLOAT : %.20f\n", f);
    }
}
```

and seeing following output

```txt
DOUBLE: 3.00000000000000040000
FLOAT : 3.00000000000000000000
```

125 is 5<sup>3</sup> so log(125)/log(5) should ideally give 3.  Where does this output come from 3.00000000000000040000 in case of double?  Unable to understand the reason (internally what is causing this) any light on this would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

One of the problems with floating point representations (float and double) is that they don’t store values in decimal, but instead store them in a binary form. This means that many numbers are approximately, rather than precisely like integers, equal to their desired value. The approximation is better when you have more precision.

In Java, double uses an **eight byte** representation, while float uses **four byte**. Thus, doubles are generally going to be better (or at least no worse) than floats at representing any particular value. I expect that this is the reason why the designers of Java chose double to be the representation used for floating point literals.

> So basically when you say ‘float’ in Java you actually declare a 32-bit 1–8–23 IEEE float, and similarly a ‘double’ is a 64-bit 1–11–52 IEEE float.

Comment: This answer is extremely misleading.  The truth is that these errors have absolutely nothing to do with whether the numbers are stored in decimal or binary.  The natural logarithms of 5 and of 125 are irrational, so you'd get errors no matter which base you stored them in.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem we are talking about the precision anomaly of double and float here and this precision thing will be there if you do simple arithmetic also, not limited to logarithms as special case

Comment: Yes, and your answer would be correct if we were talking about simple arithmetic with decimal numbers.  But when it comes to dealing with transcendental numbers, there are errors no matter how you represent them; so the whole decimal versus binary thing that your answer talks about is completely irrelevant.